# Fazer meu site abrir no aplicativo automaticamente quando acesso pelo Navegador

Tags: android, android-studio, app

eu tenho um aplicativo para Android feito no Android Studio, e simples um webview, oque devo fazer no app para reconhecer o site e abrir ele no app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o [Firebase Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/?hl=pt-br).

Com o Firebase Indexing você pode criar URLs que ao serem acessadas encaminham o usuário para dentro do seu aplicativo. Além disso você pode criar caminhos como *url/configuracoes* para que o Aplicativo abra na tela de Configuração por exemplo.
O serviço é gratuito e de fácil implementação, basta abrir uma conta no Firebase, cria um Projeto, e seguir a documentação. Aproveite para descobrir outros serviços gratuitos do Firebase para otimizar o seu app.